# Probability maths question

Tags: probability

Four children Anne, Jordan, David, and Katie are to be seated in a single row on a bench.

If Anne must always sit on the left hand side, write out all the possible sitting arrangements.

How many arrangements are possible if there are no restrictions on seating?

Comment: Any thoughts?  This can be done entirely by hand, after all.

Comment: Also, is this a homework problem? If it is, you should show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you will have to have in mind is that first of all you put Anne in the left, so, there are two possible ways for Anne to sit:

Anne, person, person, person

or

person, Anne, person, person.

Then you must have in mind also that in each place you should put one of the 3 persons left so there will be 2 times 3! ways of arrange them. If the question say's left and means that 'left with respect to all others' then it is just the first case and you will have 1 times 3! ways to arrange them.

Anne, person, person, person.

What I thought was left 'with respect to the center of all person's'.

Try to do by yourself the case that there is no restriction if you can understand what I've done above. The answer is 4!.

I cannot comment this in your question but you should put what you have done to solve the question. And put the tag of homework-like problems.